# Regex to allow negative values with maximum of 4 decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a little help with changing the following regex to allow negative numbers. It needs to allow decimal numbers of up to a maximum of 4 decimal places, which it already does.

```
/^\d+(\.\d{1,4})?$/
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Just add `-?` (hyphen, optional) after the `^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the - in the character class with optional(?)

```
 /^[-+]?\d+(\.\d{1,4})?$/
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put `-?` before the first digit - "optionally match a minus sign"

Answer (score 0):

The following allows for integer numbers (`123`), integer with 1 to 4 fractional part (`123.1234`) and only 1 to 4 fractional part (`.1234`), that's usually accepted as a valid number. All options can be prefixed by plus or minus signs:

```
/^[-+]?(?:\d+|\d*(?:\.\d{1,4})?)$/
```

The `(?:xxx)` construction is preferred to `(xxx)` when we're not interested to capture the matches, because it requires less resources.